# Where the User Profile Pictures are stored in database

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, picture-library, spprofilephotostore

Where the User Profile Pictures are stored in database? And in which database is it?

I've lost all the users' photos in high resolution from SharePoint Profiles and trying to find the way to restore these.

Comment: If the hq pictures have been lost in SP, you could just re-do the picture synchronization on UPSA. It's basically harmless to overwrite the whatever pictures users have on their profiles currently by the ones imported with the synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Profile pictures are stored in the content database of MySites!

If you have changed your domain name for the SharePoint site, then you will not be able to retrieve it unless you change the path of the pictures using powershell may be.

Answer (score 6):

If you are importing the User's picture from the AD, a full sync will fix it.

Basically User Profile Pictures stored in the `User Photos/Profile Pictures` folder on the root of mysite host url. Url will be like this " `http://Mysite url/User Photos/Profile Pictures"`

In this folder, you will be 3 sizes of a sing users.

If you have backup of your site, then restore it and copy the pictures from restored site to here.